# Issues reading Text File

Tags: python, file, text

I have an issue reading a text file.

I have a txt file of ~600kb with 3832 lines an max ~700 characters in one line. The content of this file is partly destroyed and I want to read out the not destroyed part of it. Thats working, but only if I deleted the first destroyed part of it (576 lines).

Is there any restriction in python regards lines and characters?

My first step is:

```
f = open ("file","r")
with open("file", "r") as input_file:
    with open('file_new', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
           if "limits" in line:
               output_file.write(line)
f.close()
```

Afterwards I proceed with different steps in my code. But already my first step is not working correctly. Also when I'm trying to delete the first lines its not working :(

Has anyone an idea what I can do instead of deleting the first 576 lines manually?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the f = open, and f.close statements.

Comment: What do you mean by 'destroyed'?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what is happening when you say "not working correctly". Is there an error message? What are you expecting to happen that didn't happen?

Comment: Also out of interest how did you know the first 576 lines were destroyed? You could potentially use "that" logic to start reading from that location.

Comment: @Jaynath
Destroyed means that there is something like that 69 6E 63 6F 6D 70 72 65 73 73 69 62 instead of real text and I know that this is wrong.

Comment: @Jaynath: Actually I dont really need the f.close statement at that point of my code, but the f = open

Comment: @CalmStorm: I know it because I know how the file looks when it is not 'destroyed'. Maybe destroyed is the wrong wording, but I don't know how I can describe it better

Comment: @BurhanKhalid with 'not working correctly' I mean that my program gives no output when I am not deleting the first 576 lines. The output file is empty. I have no error message or anything that points to a problem

Comment: @JayanthKoushik Sorry, I dont need the f open and f close statements. My bad!

Comment: Did you try to print 'repr(line)' in the cycle to see what happens?

Comment: I dont know repr(line). How do I have to use that?

Comment: @user2834508 You should now explore into what 69 6E... means? Is that non ASCII characters in your text file? If yes then you can easily write a program. However you should certainly come up with a definition of "destroyed", I have a feeling you mean hex chars or some such thing.

Comment: @CalmStorm I found out its hex code. The file shouldn't contain hex code. It should contain only clear text. That's what I meant with "The content of this file is partly destroyed". Actually thats not true now. Its just not translate into clear text.

Comment: Does anybody know how I can convert a hex file into an ASCII file?